# Selecting Blocks of n rows within a given range and sort them descending - VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I´m learning the very basics of VBA coding in excel. I am trying to create a VBA code to select blocks of "n" (a given numbers of rows) within a range and then sort these rows chosen from the highest to the lowest number. Please see the example below. Any ideas?. Thank in advance.

Desired range.

[image]

Selected blocks

[image]

Desired sorting

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try working through this.

```
sub meh()
    dim i as long, rws as long

    rws=4

    with worksheets(1)
        for i=rws+1 to .cells(.rows.count, "A").end(xlup).row step rws *2
            with .cells(i, "A").resize(rws, 1)
                .Sort Key1:=.cells(1), Order1:=xldescending, _
                      Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlNo
            end with
        next i
    end with

end sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. The result desired is a little bit off. I am getting: 1 2 3 4 4 3 2 1 4 3 2 1 4 3 2 1 ...

Comment: You might have missed an edit. I realized after posting that it was supposed to be Step rws * 2 not Step rws and edited it to fix.

Comment: You are correct. I´ve missed an edit. It worked perfectly. Thank you very much!

Comment: Dear Jeeped, let´s say my range has a header. Is there a workaround to start all the process from the second cell in that range down?

Comment: change for i=rws+1 to for i=rws+2